# Matlab: filtering large array elements, quicker alternative to logical indexing?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a large, three-dimensional dataset of floats, roughly 500 million elements (3000 x 300 x 600).

I want to make elements that are below or above certain thresholds zero. Logical indexing can do this, e.g.

```
cut_in = 0.5
cut_out = 6
Hs(Hs<cut_in) = 0 ;
Hs(Hs>cut_out) = 0 ;
```

The problem is that this is painfully slow for me, what with the large data size. The above code takes 240 seconds to run on my computer. Is there a quicker way I can do this?

Many thanks

Comment: Doing this with 500M elements... that's really the fastest way you're ever going to get. `logical` indexing is amongst the fastest methods to slice and index into arrays.  You have to consider 500M elements in terms of how much memory this occupies.  500,000,000 * 8 bytes / number = 4 GBytes.  I also am not able to reconstruct your timing.  I've just tried this on my computer with random values and this takes around 2.4 seconds for me. You probably have other large variables that are factoring in to the amount of memory you have available.

Comment: Put the two indices together with a logical `&`. And I don't think the problem is indexing: it's memory access over a wide range of values. If more than half of your array would be changed, consider using `Hstmp = Hs; Hs=zeros(size(Hstmp)); inds=Hstmp>cut_in & HStmp<cut_out; Hs(inds)=Hstmp(inds);`. And I'm not even sure that will help, just worth a try.

Comment: The code is optimal, but the performance surprises me. When I run the code with 3000 x 300 x 200 (more is not possible with my matlab) it takes only 3 seconds. I assume you exceeded your memory and Matlab is starting to swap data.

Comment: I just tried `X = rand( 3000, 300, 600 ); tic; X( X < 0.25 ) = 0; toc` for "fun" and it takes ~20 seconds.

Comment: @MatthiasW. could you please try with a threshold of 0.9, just to have a feeling about the times involved?:) My computer is already lagging by looking at these data sizes...

Comment: @AndrasDeak: about 275 seconds, but it made my system really unresponsive so that I wouldn't recommend to test this. ;) But ~90% of 500 Million double values randomly distributed... rather swapping-intensive than CPU-load intensive. :D

Comment: @MatthiasW. thanks a lot:) This sort of verifies the suspicions of Daniel.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, it looks like the above is the best way of doing it but I will try your suggestion @andras.

Comment: Just a comment: quite a lot of the data is nans, representing land masses (the data is a time dependent quantity over latitude and longitude). Would it be possible to somehow only apply the above operation to the non-nan values, and could this improve performance?

Comment: @EngStan I think `nan`s already throw a `false` for such arithmetic checks. Have you considered using a sparse array instead of a dense one? Assuming you don't actually need those `nan`s there.

Comment: Benchmarks have limited use without specifying MATLAB version

Comment: What version of MATLAB do you have? What are your hardware specifications? What is the format of your data? How much precision do you need? Is your data set  mostly empty/undefined?

Comment: @EngStan: How many nans do you have? Maybe there are better data structures.

Comment: I am running version R2013b, Intel Core i5 processor (2.9 GHz) with 8 Gb RAM.
@Daniel, it varies between the datasets but for the dataset described above about 45% of the data are nans.
Andras thanks for the tip, I had not heard of sparse matrices before. I understand that sparse matrices have to be 2D. However, it seems that the sparse matrices (2D slices of the dataset) take up more space that their non sparse counterparts, is this because I am considering them in the wrong way?

Comment: @EngStan With 45% sparse is not a good solution here. Knowing that numbers I don't see anything which could be improved, except getting some additional ram or make more available (stop other applications).

Answer (score 0):

As @rayryeng and @AndrasDeak point out in comments to your question, logical indexing is usually fastest, though your runtimes suggest that you are probably limited by memory (and being forced to swap onto disk) rather than by the actual speed of the indexing.

One surprising alternative that can win out in this case is for loops. This is because logical indexing requires three passes through the array (once for each inequality test, and once to change the data), whereas a for loop only requires one pass through the array.

## Benchmarks

So I ran these tests (and accidentally doubled the array size) on a machine with 8 GB memory:

```
>> A = randn(6000,300,600);
>> cut_in = -1;
>> cut_out = 1;
```

Using a for loop:

```
>> tic; for i=1:numel(A), if A(i)<cut_in || A(i)>cut_out, A(i)=0; end; end; toc
Elapsed time is 597.384884 seconds.
```

Using logical indexing:

```
>> tic; A(A<cut_in | A>cut_out) = 0; toc
Elapsed time is 1619.105332 seconds.
```

And just for laughs (had some time on my hands waiting for the benchmarks to run), here is a compiled for loop:

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    double *A = mxGetPr(prhs[0]);
    size_t N = mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[0]);
    double cut_in = *mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
    double cut_out = *mxGetPr(prhs[2]);
    // You're not supposed to do in-place operations! Don't do this!
    for (ptrdiff_t ii=0; ii<N; ii++) {
        if ((A[ii]<cut_in) || (A[ii]>cut_out))
            A[ii] = 0;
    }
}
```

And benchmarked:

```
>> mex -v CXXOPTIMFLAGS="-O3 -DNDEBUG" -largeArrayDims apply_threshold.cpp
>> tic; apply_threshold(A,cut_in,cut_out); toc
Elapsed time is 529.994643 seconds
```

One thing to keep in mind is that we are operating in a regime where accessing the swap space is the main bottleneck in performance, and so benchmark results can vary, even within the same machine, depending on what's currently in main memory (vs. what needs to be swapped in) and what kind of background processes are running.

Comment: What version of MATLAB? What hardware?

Comment: R2015b, i7-4610M, 16GB, 25 seconds for the loop, 9 seconds for the logical index.

Comment: @excaza, thank you for the additional benchmark; I get similar times as you when I run it on a machine that is able to hold the array in main memory (R2014b, RHEL 6.5, 2x E5-2680, 256GB). However, it seems that the original poster is operating in a regime where swapping is the performance bottleneck, hence this answer was run on much older hardware (R2014b, RHEL 6.5, 2x Opteron 248, 8GB).

Comment: @excaza haha, nice setup. :D @user1877862, not too important but it seems you've got a typo in `>> A = randn(6000,300,600;`